# reading json dev mode works fine but not in production mode

Tags: json, next.js, readfile

I was saving some settings into a JSON file and read it via an import in next JS dev mode and its working fine but when I build the application and start production mode with yarn start it works but if I changed some settings inside that JSON file it doesn't see the changes, why that happens?

```
import file from '~/../settings-file.json'
```